# Updating totalItems in angular-ui-grid with external

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, angular-ui-grid

I am using external pagination in AngularJS's ui-grid as described here:

http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/314_external_pagination

That updates a special field of totalItems when new page is arrived:

```
var getPage = function() {
// skipped some part
$http.get(url)
.success(function (data) {
  $scope.gridOptions.totalItems = 100;
  // updating grid object with data
});
```

};

My only difference to the standard example is that I have gridOptions inside an object that is passed to my directive, that has a grid inside it:

```
// Line is called right after I receive a page of data from server
$scope.gridObj.gridOptions.totalItems= response.TotalItems;
```

If I initialize this field before grid is shown on screen (together with configuration) then it remains at the value that I set back then (and obviously, it is not adequate to set of data I receive later, during runtime). But when I alter it later after I call my loading method (that returns current "page" as well as value for totalItems), the change is not picked up by ui-grid. If it is not initialized at startup, again, I could not set this to any value.

How am I to successfully modify the totalItems parameter for the ui-grid during runtime? Can I possibly re-trigger some grid update manually?

Comment: Hi, i had the same behaviour. I think the example misses the parameter `useExternalPagination: true` .. after adding that, it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that assigning `totalItems` within a `$timeout` works nicely for now. This was necessary because ui-grid *was* updating the value, just not to what I was expecting.

**Update:**
In my case I need to show all filtered items across all pages, which there is no API for. So for now I've implemented an angular filter, included below. `GridRow` objects have a visible flag set to `true` when filters have not filtered them out from the result set.

Example:

```
angular.filter('renderableRows', function() {
  return function(allRows) {
    var renderables = [];

    angular.forEach(allRows, function(row) {
      if(row.visible) {
        renderables.push(row);
      }
    });

    return renderables;
  };
});

$timeout(function() {
  $scope.gridOptions.totalItems = $filter('renderableRows')($scope.gridApi.grid.rows).length;
});
```